# Laravel Passport post route test on postman

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, postman, laravel-passport

I set up Laravel Passport and started to create a few Get routes to get some data, that worked fine.

Now I am trying to post to get on auth token, which currently does not work:

This is my route which I call (Get route works, Post route does not work):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function ()
{;
    Route::get('users', ['as' => 'users', 'uses' => 'ApiController@users']);
    Route::post('login/{id}/{name}', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'ApiController@login']);
});
```

The method in my ApiController looks currently like this:

```
public function login(Request $request, $id, $name)
{
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $id   = $request->id;
        $name = $request->name;

        $inquiry = new Inquiry();
        $inquiry->user_id = $id;
        $inquiry->user_name = $name;

        if($inquiry->save())
        {
            return redirect()->route('inquiry.index')->with('success', 'Success.');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('inquiry.index')->with('error', 'An error accured.')->withInput();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dd("Use Post.");
    }
}
```

I tried to call it with following options[image]:

**Edit**

I somehow managed to get this work after many hours, but still dont understand something.

First I did following:

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->code) // this holds a token I need for the code parameter in the post 
...
```

With that I could get the token for the code parameter, but I think there is a better way to do that.

And finally this is now how I get the access + refresh token:

[image]

But there has to be a better way to get the code token of the callback request ($request->code), instead of dumping it and copying it.

Comment: You can save it with session or store in database

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have your login route inside a route group with auth:api on it. This means the user needs to be authenticated to even be able to authenticate. Just remove the login route outside the group and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `Passport::routes` method within the boot method of your  `AuthServiceProvider`. **This method will register the routes** necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens, clients, and personal access tokens:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
}
```

`/oauth/authorize` route is already defined by the `Passport::routes` method. You do not need to manually define this route.

Comment: So how would the complete route look like then, currently I run valet so my url look something like this: `http://79f123saf.ngrok.io`, so I tried this url: `http://79f123saf.ngrok.io/api/oauth/authorize` and this one `http://79f123saf.ngrok.io/oauth/authorize` with the option I posted above in my question but I get a `TokenMismatchException` error message on `/oauth/authorize` and a `NotFoundHttpException` on `/api/oauth/authorize` Thus I do have the correct boot method inside my AuthServiceProvider